# Using sine rule to prove triangle congruence

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, triangles, congruences-geometry

The following problem looks like it should be easy, but I don't know how to prove it rigorously. All I know is the sine rule should be applied somewhere.

> Let $ABC$ be triangle with angles $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ and corresponding sides $a,b,c.$ Suppose that $\beta'$ and $\gamma'$ are angles such that $\alpha + \beta' + \gamma' = \pi$ and $\dfrac{b}{\sin{\beta'}} = \dfrac{c}{\sin{\gamma'}}$. Prove that $\beta' = \beta$ and $\gamma' = \gamma$.

I tried doing a proof by contradiction. Assume without loss of generality that $\beta' > \beta$. Then $\gamma' < \gamma$.

Now because of the sine rule: $\frac{b}{\sin{\beta}} = \frac{c}{\sin{\gamma}}$

And the statement of the problem tells us that $\frac{b}{\sin{\beta'}} = \frac{c}{\sin{\gamma'}}$.

Thus, $\frac{\sin{\beta}}{\sin{\gamma}} = \frac{\sin{\beta'}}{\sin{\gamma'}}$. Now since $\beta' > \beta$, then $\sin{\beta'} > \sin{\beta}$, and since $\gamma' < \gamma$, then $\sin{\gamma'} < \sin{\gamma}$. But if this is true, then $\frac{\sin{\beta}}{\sin{\gamma}} < \frac{\sin{\beta'}}{\sin{\gamma'}}$, which is a contradiction with what we said before.

Therefore, $\beta = \beta'$ and thus $\gamma = \gamma'$.

But the problem with this proof is that $\sin{\beta'}$ is not necessarily greater than $\sin{\beta}$, if $\beta'$ is greater than $\pi/2$ for example.

Comment: HINT. $\beta+\gamma=\beta'+\gamma'$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The question doesn't forbid cases like $\beta' = \beta + 2\pi$ and $\gamma' = \gamma - 2\pi$?

Comment: @peterwhy This is a geometry problem, in which angles greater than $2 \pi$ and less than 0 do not make sense.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca I can get that far, but how to follow on from there?

Comment: Set $\theta=\beta+\gamma=\beta'+\gamma'$ and in your equation $$\frac{\sin{\beta}}{\sin{\gamma}} = \frac{\sin{\beta'}}{\sin{\gamma'}}$$ substitute: $\gamma=\theta-\beta$ and $\gamma'=\theta-\beta'$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From $\frac{\sin{\beta}}{\sin{\gamma}} = \frac{\sin{\beta'}}{\sin{\gamma'}}$, using $\pi = \alpha + \beta +\gamma = \alpha + \beta' + \gamma'$,

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin{\beta}}{\sin{\gamma}} &= \frac{\sin{\beta'}}{\sin{\gamma'}}\\
\frac{\sin(\pi-\alpha - \gamma)}{\sin{\gamma}} &= \frac{\sin(\pi-\alpha - \gamma')}{\sin{\gamma'}}\\
\frac{\sin(\alpha + \gamma)}{\sin{\gamma}} &= \frac{\sin(\alpha + \gamma')}{\sin{\gamma'}}\\
\frac{\sin\alpha\cos\gamma+\cos\alpha\sin\gamma}{\sin{\gamma}} &= \frac{\sin\alpha\cos\gamma'+\cos\alpha\sin\gamma'}{\sin{\gamma'}}\\
\sin\alpha\cot\gamma+\cos\alpha &= \sin\alpha\cot\gamma'+\cos\alpha\\
\cot\gamma &= \cot\gamma'\\
\gamma &= \gamma'
\end{align*}$$

Assuming all $\alpha, \beta,\gamma,\beta',\gamma'$ are strictly between $0$ and $\pi$, as mentioned in the comments.